# SQL query which has multiple conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, where-clause

I am trying to execute the below query but it is not satisfying the conditions that I mentioned in the where clause. It has to first pick the terms which are in 36,48,60 and if the term is 48 then the value should not be between -107 to -305 and if the term is 60 the value should not between 0 to 87 and not contains -1304,-1204 and if term is 36 then value should not be more than -300. But when I ran the query it gave all the values that I mentioned in the exclusion. Please help

```
select distinct
Market,
(select top 1 LDCAccountidentifier from siteidentification where siteoid=#final.siteoid) as CustAccNum,
SiteOID,
RtlrContractIdentifier,
ContractOID,
ContractType,
ContractStatus,
Term,
ProductCode,
SigningDate,
FlowStartDate,
FlowEndDate,
RenewalDate,
Dateadd(dd,(term*365/12),flowstartdate) as [FSD+Term],
datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,(term*365/12),flowstartdate),RenewalDate) as DifferenceinDays,
UsageFrom,
UsageTo,
DealFSD,
DealFED,
ContractUpdateDate,
UsageUpdateDate,
DealUpdateDate,
replace(replace(ErrorMessage, char(13),', '), Char(10),'') as ErrorMessage
from #final
where term in(36,48,60)
or (term=48 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1460,flowstartdate),RenewalDate) not between -107 and -305)
or (term=60 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1825,flowstartdate),RenewalDate)not between 0 and 87)
or (term=60 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1825,flowstartdate),RenewalDate) not in(-1304,-1204))
or (term=36 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1095,flowstartdate),RenewalDate)<-300)
```

Comment: Define your `select statement` we don't know this use for.. And which `rdbms`? `sql` just language..

Comment: @dwir182 sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using braces for setting precedence of OR operator

```
select distinct
Market,
(select top 1 LDCAccountidentifier from siteidentification where siteoid=#final.siteoid) as CustAccNum,
SiteOID,
RtlrContractIdentifier,
ContractOID,
ContractType,
ContractStatus,
Term,
ProductCode,
SigningDate,
FlowStartDate,
FlowEndDate,
RenewalDate,
Dateadd(dd,(term*365/12),flowstartdate) as [FSD+Term],
datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,(term*365/12),flowstartdate),RenewalDate) as DifferenceinDays,
UsageFrom,
UsageTo,
DealFSD,
DealFED,
ContractUpdateDate,
UsageUpdateDate,
DealUpdateDate,
replace(replace(ErrorMessage, char(13),', '), Char(10),'') as ErrorMessage
from #final
where term in(36,48,60) and (
(term=48 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1460,flowstartdate),RenewalDate) not between -305 and -107)
or (term=60 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1825,flowstartdate),RenewalDate)not between 0 and 87)
or (term=60 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1825,flowstartdate),RenewalDate) not in(-1304,-1204))
or (term=36 and datediff(dd,Dateadd(dd,1095,flowstartdate),RenewalDate)<-300))
```

Comment: I don't even see the point of the `WHERE term IN (36, 48, 60)` clause at this point, but you seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The above query isn't correct, you should be using a WHEN - THEN condition in order to achieve your desired result.

You should ideally be using a case in SQL for the same.
Something like below:

```
SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN <Condition> AND <Condition>
            THEN
               --do your select query--
        WHEN <Condition> AND <Condition>
            THEN
                --do your select query-
        ELSE
            -- default task --
     END
  FROM <table name>
```